# How to make useQuery on every activation of paginate function in next js

Tags: next.js, usehooks-ts

The paginate function gets the number of the page to be drawn and changes the skip to cut off unnecessary elements. How can I make a new request every time the function fires? Of course, you can put the request itself into a function, but there is probably a more correct and elegant solution through useEffect or useCallback. Tell me how to do it right?

```
export const useReviewsList = () => {
let skip = `0`
const limit = `2`

const { isLoading, data: response } = useQuery(
    ['reviews pagination', limit, skip],
    () => ReviewService.pagination(skip, limit)
)

const paginate = (number: number) => {
    skip = String(number * Number(limit))
    console.log(skip)
}

return { isLoading, response, paginate, limit }}
```

Comment: _"How can I make a new request every time the function fires?"_ - You'll want to move `skip` into a state variable: `const [skip, setSkip] = useState('0')`. Then update the state value inside `paginate` with `setSkip(String(number * Number(limit)))`. This will trigger a re-render and a new request will be made from `useQuery`, using the new value for `skip`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really did it and it worked!